# Give a graph G find all the blob of nodes in this graph such that node.color attribute = specific color

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Given a graph, assume connected, write a C++ function that finds and returns a connected blob of nodes in this graph that satisfy a specific condition e.g. node.color=green.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, please read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Show us some of your code please.

Comment: I don't know where to start. Do I traverse the graph and collect all the nodes that have color = green. and then try to find the biggest connected graph in that set of nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach you can implement is to traverse the graph and check each node's color.

In C++ish pseudocode:

```
for (auto & node : graph.nodes) {
  if (node.visited) continue;
  node.visited = true;
  if (node.color != "green") continue;
  size_t count = 1;

  // Assuming node.neighbours contains Node* elements. Do a DFS from this node.
  std::stack<Node*> todo(node.neighbours.begin(), node.neighbours.end());
  while (!todo.empty()) {
    auto n = todo.top(); todo.pop();
    if (n->visited) return;
    n->visited = true;

    if (n->color == "green") {
      // Further explore all neighbours.
      count++;
      for (auto n2 : n->neighbours) {
        todo.push(n2);
      } 
    }
  }
  cout << "node " << node.id << " has " << count << " neighbours" << endl;
}
```

Modifying this code to aggregate this into the "blob of connected nodes" and returning the largest such blob is left as an exercise.

Alternatively, you can do a regular traversal over all the nodes and use a [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), modified to keep track of set sizes. As you traverse them, each green node becomes a set by itself, and you join it with its green neighbours if they belong to no set (if not visited) or different sets (if visited). The largest connected blob is then simply the largest union.